# Hello World with go on the appengine: ctypes error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, go, ctypes

I'm trying to deploy a go app on the appengine and followed this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/gettingstarted/helloworld?hl=de

But `dev_appserver.py gopath/myapp/` results in this strange error message:

```
C:\Users\praktikant\Desktop\google_appengine>dev_appserver.py gopath/myapp/
INFO     2013-07-16 10:43:17,565 sdk_update_checker.py:244] Checking for updates
 to the SDK.
INFO     2013-07-16 10:43:18,779 sdk_update_checker.py:288] This SDK release is
newer than the advertised release.
WARNING  2013-07-16 10:43:18,799 api_server.py:314] Could not initialize images
API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module.
INFO     2013-07-16 10:43:18,815 api_server.py:138] Starting API server at: http
://localhost:51413
INFO     2013-07-16 10:43:18,825 api_server.py:509] Applying all pending transac
tions and saving the datastore
INFO     2013-07-16 10:43:18,828 api_server.py:512] Saving search indexes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\praktikant\Desktop\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 182
, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Users\praktikant\Desktop\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py", line 178
, in _run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Users\praktikant\Desktop\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\deva
ppserver2\devappserver2.py", line 695, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\praktikant\Desktop\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\deva
ppserver2\devappserver2.py", line 688, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "C:\Users\praktikant\Desktop\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\deva
ppserver2\devappserver2.py", line 663, in start
    self._dispatcher.start(apis.port, request_data)
  File "C:\Users\praktikant\Desktop\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\deva
ppserver2\dispatcher.py", line 161, in start
    servr.start()
  File "C:\Users\praktikant\Desktop\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\deva
ppserver2\server.py", line 936, in start
    self._watcher.start()
  File "C:\Users\praktikant\Desktop\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\deva
ppserver2\file_watcher.py", line 37, in start
    watcher.start()
  File "C:\Users\praktikant\Desktop\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\deva
ppserver2\win32_file_watcher.py", line 74, in start
    raise ctypes.WinError()
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid
```

My system is windows 7, 64-bit. I downloaded and unzipped the google-appengine sdk for go version 1.8.1 64-bit. GOPATH and GOROOT environment variables are created and set to the folders in the unzipped sdk directory. My Python is 2.7.5 64-bit.

The error message sounded like it was python related and I found this question on stackoverflow: [Windows Error in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15530866/windows-error-in-google-app-engine)

The general consensus on stackoverflow is that gae version 1.7.6 had a few bugs, the accepted answer recommends downgrading back to 1.7.5 .

But today the current version is 1.8.1. Is this a bug that has still not been fixed, or a problem with my configuration ? If the problem is related to my configuration, how can I fix it ?

**UPDATE:**
The update checker prints the information that the sdk release that I am using is newer than the advertised version. I downloaded the sdk from here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Go

Why the version from the google servers is newer than the advertised version puzzles me, too.

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment ? And why would anyone vote to close this question ? I think it is objective and clear.

Comment: Whats with this line in your startup "This SDK release is
newer than the advertised release."  I would investigate why you are getting this.

Comment: @TimHoffman That's a good thought, but I've been getting that warning, too, for at least the past week.  1.8.1 is clearly the current version, so that warning seems to just be a glitch in Google's version-checking system.

Comment: @lhk Even though 1.8.1 has been out for a while, given that the last line of your error message is the same as in the question you linked to, it sure seems worth attempting the downgrade to 1.7.5 and seeing if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried to move the google_appengine folder to other place (e.g. C:\)? The error seems to be related to devserver failing to observe changes in your source directory.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have created the required folders **bin**, **pkg** and most importantly the **src** folder in your GOPATH folder because that's the folder dev_appserver.py is trying to setup a filewatcher on and if it doesn't exist you will get this error.

You mentioned that you had setup your GOPATH to the gopath folder in the SDK but that folder is empty by default so that's why I think that this might be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Given that GOPATH and GOROOT are environment variables, shouldn't `dev_appserver.py gopath/myapp/`  actually be `dev_appserver.py "%GOPATH%/myapp/"` ?

Comment: Inside the folder google-appengine which contains the sdk, there is a directory named gopath. i created an environment variable named GOPATH which points to this directory and stored the project files inside of it. the command "dev_appserver.py" is called from within the google-appengine folder, so gopath/myapp/ is the correct path to my app. If the command would be executed outside of the appengine folder, then you would be right. Then I would have to use the environment variable

Answer (score 0):

if not works I'm find a solution

in the file

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py

add:

> _WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES = [
>       'msvcrt',     #added by me for local host compatibility
>       '_ctypes',
>       'ctypes',     #end

this for me fix ctypes problem